# Being able to Save and Open, my test based Python Game

Tags: python, save

So, I am currently working on a Text based game for School Coursework, and I need to know how to save it, and open it again. If anyone could give me tips or help, here is the code:

```
import random

#Variables
char1_strength = round(10+(random.randint(1,12)/(random.randint(1,4))))
char1_skill = round(10+(random.randint(1,12)/(random.randint(1,4))))
char2_strength = round(10+(random.randint(1,12)/(random.randint(1,4))))
char2_skill = round(10+(random.randint(1,12)/(random.randint(1,4))))


#Game
print ("You are going to play as two different characters, we will now name them.")
input ("Press enter to continue.")

char1_name = input ("Choose your first character's name: ")
print ("So your Character name is",char1_name,".")
print("We are now going to determine Skill and Strength for" , char1_name,"...")
input ("Press enter to continue.")
print ("So,",char1_name+"'s Strength is",char1_strength,".")
print ("So,",char1_name+"'s Skill is",char1_skill,".")
print ("So, your Strength is",char1_strength,"and your Skill is",char1_skill,".")

print (" ")

input ("We are now going to do your second Character, press enter to continue:")

print (" ")

char2_name = input ("Choose your second character's name: ")
print ("So your Character name is",char2_name,".")
print ("We are now going to determine Skill and Strength for" , char2_name,"...")
input ("Press enter to continue.")
print ("So,",char2_name+"'s Strength is",char2_strength,".")
print ("So,",char2_name+"'s Skill is",char2_skill,".")
print ("So, your Strength is",char2_strength,"and your Skill is",char2_skill,".")
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to save data for later use for a program is File I/O. Simple I/O with a file looks a bit like this:

```
#Open existing/create file for write operations
with open('savefile.txt', 'w') as file:
    #Write data
    file.write('some_data\n')
    file.write('some_other_data')

#Open existing file for read operations
with open('savefile.txt', 'r') as file:
    #Get all lines and convert input to str
    some_stat = ''.join(file.readlines())
    print(some_stat)
```

In simple terms, the first paragraph creates a file and prepares it for string input; if there is an existing file with the provided name in the directory, it will preform actions on that file. Data is then inputted via `write` method. The file is automatically closed after the `with` statement.

`savefile.txt` is then opened again, but prepared for reading rather then input. The data is retrieved via `readlines` and converted to a string format, and then finally `print`ed.

The format of the text file is up to you. You may want to separate data via newlines, or some other method, but this should be clearly decided on before implementation.

If you are confused about something, check out this tutorial:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm

Answer (score 0):

well, you can use json as serializer and standard IO.

```
import json

f = open("out.txt", "w");
f.write(json.dumps({"name":"Alice", "Strength": 18}));
f.close();
```